# Как сделать генерацию уникального id для обьекта

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Обычно, я не задавался этим вопросом, а использовал id обьекта который автоинкрементом создавался. То есть я искал объекты по их иду который автоинкрементный `$post = Post::find(1);`. И часто замечал что в больших приложениях генерируют уникальные рандомные идентификаторы для объектов.

Например: если создают первую категорию, то ее ид (автоинкрементный) будет 1, а какой нибудь `gid`, `pid`, `cid` будут равны `10254`.
Вот как это называется? И как сделать что бы генерировался рандомный но уникальный ид для обьекта?

Comment: Честно сказать, не знаю, как там с лучшими практиками, но я как то для себя делал, так: брал значения всех столбцов строки(особенно вместе с инкриментированным id и временем создания), в строку конкотинировал, и из этого находил хеш(например md5).

Comment: `max() + 1` вам в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни какого смысла отказываться от id в пользу других идентификаторов нет, если только не стоит цель обфусцировать данные по отношению к внешнему миру.

Тогда используется UUID, либо просто произвольную строку. Уникальность достигается малой вероятностью коллизий. Хотя проверка тоже не помешает, в случае с mysql на поле следует повесить индекс UNIQUE, это так же ускорит выборку. Но не быстрее чем привычная выборка по id.

---

В дополнение, раз уж речь зашла о URL, то разумнее использование ЧПУ. Обычно это просто название на транслите.

`site.name/post/generacija_unikalnogo_id`

Comment: смысл в том, что бы при построении ссылки вида `site.name/post/1` поставить не автоинкрементный ид, а рандомный что б для первого поста (в базе) ссылка не была показал выше, а что б примерно так `site.name/post/205213`.

Comment: @Alex_01 начните автоинкремент в таблице таблице с 205212 :)

Comment: @Alex_01, это и называется обфусцировать. Добавьте в таблицу поле `code VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL` и записывайте в него [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) повесьте на него UNIQUE как и говорилось и далее поиск по полю `code`.
Получите `site.name/post/b2f7f9d7-dd65-11e6-885b-c5cfbd441eca`

Comment: @teran так не интересно)

Comment: @Gedweb я не хочу использовать 'slug'

Comment: В распределенных системах не используют `increment` а используют `uuid` для избежания коллизий.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться штатной функцией PHP: `uniqid()`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

И сохранять в базе, в поле uid, например, каждый раз при сохранении. При передаче второго параметра в функцию будет достаточно уникальный id. Пример сгенерированной строки:

> 587fd609b30903.05749207